# Como eliminar div clonado dentro de otro div

Tags: jquery

**Listo ya lo organice, lo que busco es eliminar o remover eldiv que seclono en campobuscar cuando le de click a un mismo elemento que tenga el mismo identificador**

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      $('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
         var e = $(this).clone();
         var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");
        
         if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){
           
           
         }else{
           $(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');
         } 
     });
      
      $('#campoBusq').on('click','.elemento',function() {
         $(this).remove();
      });

      //  $('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
      //     $('#campoBusq').remove('.elemento',this);
      // });

  });
```

```css
/*----------------------Busqueda Cateoria-------------------------*/
#cont-campoBusq-relat{position: relative;}
#cont-campoBusq{width: 100%;height: 50px;margin-top: 10px;display:flex;}
/*------imgBusq*/
#cont-imgBusq .imgBusq{
 width: 100px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 18px;
 max-height: 50px;
 padding-top: 5px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    aling-items:center;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: transparent;
 color: hsla(25,25%,9%,0.9);
 border: 6px solid hsla(12, 10%, 86%,1);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px hsla(0,12%,50%,1);
}
#cont-imgBusq .imgBusq img{max-height: 50px;}

/*----select_ThCont*/
#select_ThCont select{
 width: 80px;
 padding: 3px;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 6px;
 font-size: 17px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 max-height: 50px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: transparent;
 color: hsla(25,25%,9%,0.9);
 border: 6px solid hsla(12, 10%, 86%,1);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px hsla(0,12%,50%,1);
}
/*-----campoBusq*/
#campoBusq{
 width: 900px;
 padding: 6px;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: transparent;
 color: hsla(25,25%,9%,0.9);
 border: 6px solid hsla(12, 10%, 86%,1);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px hsla(0,12%,50%,1);
}
/*-------buscCateg*/
#cont-buscCateg{height: 50px;margin-left: 5px;cursor: pointer;diplay:flex;}
.buscCateg{
 padding: 6px;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: hsla(25,25%,9%,0.9);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 6px solid hsla(12, 10%, 86%,1);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px hsla(0,12%,50%,1);
 background: transparent;

}
/*------categoria*/
#cont-categoria{
 left: 0;
 top: 60;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
    display:flex;
  background: palevioletred;
 
}
#categoria{
 width: 600px;
 height: 150px;
 background: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="cont-campoBusq-relat">//Inicio del cuerpo
     <div id="cont-campoBusq" class="centFRH">*Container*

              <div id="cont-imgBusq">
       <div class="imgBusq centFRHV">
        <img src="../css3/fonts_icons/buscarOjo2.svg" alt="No aparece">
          </div>
             </div>
             <div id="select_ThCont">
                  <select>
        <option><h4>TH4</h4></option>
        <option><h4>TH5</h4></option>
        <option><h4>TH6</h4></option>
        <option><h4>TH7</h4></option>
        <option><h4>TH8</h4></option>
        <option><h4>TH9</h4></option>
               </select>
         </div>
         
           <div id="campoBusq"></div>

        <div id="cont-buscCateg" class="centFRH">
       <div class="buscCateg"><h5>Buscar por Categoria</h5></div>
        </div>

        <div id="cont-categoria" class="centFRH">
          <div id="categoria">
                <option class="elemento 1" iden="1"></option>
                <option class="elemento 2" iden="2"></option>
                <option class="elemento 3" iden="3"></option>
                <option class="elemento 4" iden="4"></option>
                <option class="elemento 5" iden="5"></option>
             </div>//Fin categoria
        </div>//Fin categoria container
    </div>//Fin Container
  </div>//Fin del Cuerpo Usuario
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seria interesante cual es el error, por que no lo veo por ningún lado :D

Comment: listo espero que me ayuden

Comment: Es decir, en el buscador pones por ejemplo 'onomatopeya' y si se hace click en un div con id igual a 'onomatopeya' debe eliminarse. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: te explicare con la imagen; yo quiero que darle click a un div que en este caso son option se remueva del campo; donde solo se encuentra esta palabra (Muros al Maximo)

Comment: es decir que se remueva del campoBusq; que es donde se encuentra esta palabra(muros al maximo). Dandole click al el mismo o a la misma palabra que se encuentra en el menu

Comment: Disculpa, que se remueva a lo que le das click, o sea que se elimine de la lista?

Comment: SI AMIGO, tu le das click y como son clones debo hacer entender al codigo que me remueva solo lo que se inserta en el campobusq que tiene el mismo identificador que viene siendo su copia y que fue asignado en campoBusq